# How to create an xml element in a specific position using vb.net?

Tags: xml, vb.net, xsd, cda

I am trying to create an xml element after another element, in a specific position but the element is added inside another element and has an xmlns part added. I dont want 'xmlns' there also.
What I need to add is this:

[Where I need the element to be added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Lccc.png)

What I have tried is this:

```
        Dim cda As New XmlDocument
        Dim refChild As XmlNode = cda.SelectSingleNode("//cr:recordTarget/cr:patientRole/cr:id", NS)
        Dim newChild As XmlElement = cda.CreateElement("id")
        newChild.SetAttribute("root", "2.16.840.1.113883.2.9.4.3.1")
        newChild.SetAttribute("extension", "DLCVCN48S05L049B")
        refChild.InsertBefore(newChild, refChild.FirstChild)
```

What happens is this:

```
 <id root="2.16.840.1.113883.2.9.4.3.2" extension="PTRFMN46E69D171X" 
 assigningAuthorityName="Ministero Economia e Finanze">
 <id root="2.16.840.1.113883.2.9.4.3.1" extension="DLCVCN48S05L049B" xmlns="" />
  </id>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based in your pic seems is this what you want to do (Basdandosi nella tua immagine sembra sia questo quello che stai cercando):

```
    refChild.AppendChild(newChild)
```

But. Based on your question seems you want to do this (Ma basandosi nella domanda):

```
    Dim newChild As Xml.XmlElement = cda.CreateElement("id", cda.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI)
    newChild.SetAttribute("root", "2.16.840.1.113883.2.9.4.3.1")
    newChild.SetAttribute("extension", "DLCVCN48S05L049B")
    newChild.InnerText = " "


    If refChild.ParentNode IsNot Nothing Then
        refChild.ParentNode.InsertAfter(newChild, refChild)
    End If
```

Comment: Thank you! Adding xml element in a specific position works good! xmlns displays again, trying to find another choice for that.  :)

Comment: Ti ho aggiornato la risposta (fai attenzione alla creazione del nodo) per quanto riguarda l’attributo “xmlns”. Fammi sapere.
Good luck  ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use Xml Linq.  Find patientRole and then add new id to patientRole :

```
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Linq
Module Module1
    Const FILENAME As String = "c:\temp\test.xml"
    Sub Main()
        Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Load(FILENAME)
        Dim patientRole = doc.Descendants().Where(Function(x) x.Name.LocalName = "patientRole").FirstOrDefault()

        Dim newPatient As XElement = New XElement("id", New Object() {New XAttribute("root", "2.16.840.1.113883.2.9.4.3.2"), New XAttribute("extension", "PTRFMN46E69D171X"), New XAttribute("assigningAuthorityName", "Ministero Economia e Finanze")})
        patientRole.Add(newPatient)
    End Sub

End Module
```